# Flutter - getting issue running pod install - `image_picker_modern`

Tags: ios, flutter

I am trying to run a pod install in order to run my application, but I am getting an issue with image picker modern library, I am new on the iOS building, so, I don't what I have to do.

The log is this:

```
    WARNING: CocoaPods requires your terminal to be using UTF-8 encoding.
Consider adding the following to ~/.profile:

export LANG=en_US.UTF-8

Analyzing dependencies
Fetching podspec for `Flutter` from `.symlinks/flutter/ios`
Fetching podspec for `camera` from `.symlinks/plugins/camera/ios`
Fetching podspec for `device_info` from `.symlinks/plugins/device_info/ios`
Fetching podspec for `firebase_messaging` from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_messaging/ios`
Fetching podspec for `flutter_twitter_login` from `.symlinks/plugins/flutter_twitter_login/ios`
Fetching podspec for `flutter_webview_plugin` from `.symlinks/plugins/flutter_webview_plugin/ios`
Fetching podspec for `google_sign_in` from `.symlinks/plugins/google_sign_in/ios`
Fetching podspec for `image_picker_modern` from `.symlinks/plugins/image_picker_modern/ios`
    [!] No podspec found for `image_picker_modern` in `.symlinks/plugins/image_picker_modern/ios`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Library owner here, please use the version `0.4.13-1` instead of `0.4.12+1`. Also, this is an attempt to fix the bug reported at https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/21863#issuecomment-455055624 for the official `image_picker`. Even though that bug is closed by the collaborator, the fix is not identical to mine, and some folks still suffer from this bug, so if you experience the same, consider report back to this [Github issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/21863).

Comment: I will take a look on that

Comment: This issue applies when someone is building the iOS app? I don't have tested it there is an issue using image_picker_modern in iOS, I am trying to build the application using pod install.

Comment: Sorry I don't quite get your idea. (1) Are you the one who create this flutter app from scratch? (2) Are you running `flutter run` or `flutter build ios`, or run it from VS Code or XCode? (3) Can you find the `pubspec.yaml`? (4) To make it easier, I upgraded the library production version to `0.4.12+2`, can you just re-run your build command to see whether the error still happens?

Comment: That issue happend when I try to run pub install, that's an iOS command, or when I try to debug the application in an iPhone or in an iPhone emulator, I am updating the yaml file, I will let you know what I get

Comment: It builds now, I mean I was able to run the pod install command, I will try to build it on an iPhone now

Comment: Currently I am getting issues cuz CFD... Something does not exist